# Can't install phonegap built download .xap in windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, installation

I am using phonegap build.I can download .apk file and can install it in android devices. Phonegap built generates 
.xap files which can be downloaded but can't install in windows phones.It throws error "can't install...".Why this error occurs?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Is your windows phone device dev unlocked?
Uncertified build can only be installed if your device is dev unlocked. You can either use Application Deployment tool or windows phone power tool to install the xap after dev-unlocking your device.

Comment: Ohh...Thanks ...let me chk it.